# If I invert the argument, should I invert the constants in the equation?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I am stuck on this line that I wrote:

$$c = z^k \cdot f(1/z)$$

$$\frac{1}{c} = \frac{1}{z^k} \cdot f(z)$$

$$z^k \cdot \frac{1}{c} = f(z)$$

$f(z)$ is a polynomial, with $k = 1$ or else $f$ is not one-to-one.

Did I invert the objects correctly? (I was going for the proof of $f$ entire, one-to-one must be a linear polynomial.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think $f(z)=\frac{1}{f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}$?

Consider $f(x)=x+1$

$$\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{x+1}$$

but

$$f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{x+1}{x}$$

Comment: nice example, @DaleM.  How can I fix my proof then?  I have that f(1/z) has a pole of order k at z = 0.  Then g= z^k * f(1/z) is entire and bounded, hence constant.  so c = z^k * f(1/z), implies c / z^k = f(1/z).  how do I now finish my proof to say that f(z) is actually z^k * constant, i.e., it is a polynomial.  Use a change of variable?

Comment: nevermind, i got it.  Thanks, @daleM.